# Did Mysterio transfer E.D.I.T.H. into his helmet?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-far-from-home

When Mysterio and his team are planning their next projection attack Mysterio's helmet is seen next to the E.D.I.T.H. glasses after he has obtained access.

Did Mysterio transfer E.D.I.T.H. into his helmet?

[image: transfer]

Answer (score 14):

### Probably

The E.D.I.T.H. network is *hacked* by William (one of Beck's associates)

> William Ginther Riva: Oh, yeah. Uploading software hack to E.D.I.T.H. network, where drones will be able to create an event big enough to cover an entire city.

Beck is able to contact E.D.I.T.H.  without wearing the glasses (which he could do by radio) but when he asks E.D.I.T.H. to show him information it is displayed **inside his helmet** which is a fairly good indication that the software is now incorporated into his costume

[image]